# Hide Activity with linear layout

Tags: java, android, view

I am inflating multiple same linear layouts from one activity, and I would like to hide all of these from another activity.  How can I accomplish this?

what I tried:

```
 LinearLayout test_layout=(LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.layout.test);
 test_layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

But test_layout is always "null"

My Activity is "singleTask", so I think if I get hold of one view and close, it will close all similar views opened by this activity.

Comment: Pass the context from the first activity to the second one and then call LinearLayout test_layout=(LinearLayout)context.findViewById(R.layout.test);
But I'm not sure you should do that in the first place.

Comment: Can you hide then before launching the second activity, and then set them back to View.VISIBLE when returning to the Activity (either via onActivityResult if using startActivityForResult or using onResume)?

Comment: I will try this and let yo know. Thanks